# What could be the ideal website creation steps for non-tech users?

Tags: website-design

I am working on a *hosted website creator service* for non-tech-savy businesses owners (generic, no niche), and I am brainstorming on the user interface during the ordering/setup process.

What do you think could be the ideal scenario for such user?

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Rahul Could you point me to a better forum for such question?

Comment: The reason I closed it is because your question is very broad and you're asking for ideas. We don't accept that kind of question, but if you try reformulating it we might be able to help you. You could try asking it on Quora as well.

Answer (score 3):

we should start by gathering features we may need:

1-Clear,big(big form fields,big buttons,big notifications.. etc) , Contrast-color progress **numbered** shapes(arrows, circles , squares ... etc ).

2-Highlight current position,done and remaining with different colors.

3- Ability to move forward and back easily.

4-Showing info(example input) next to each field will be good idea.Also you can make some watermarked dummy text to each field.

5-If you intending to use ajax,pay attention to performance and show friendly message like (we are baking the cake! please wait little more:) ) such stuff will joy the user and save you more time.

6- It will be awesome if a guide messages provided on every loaded..like(Welcome Tucson! Start from here.) & ( You still can use the regular browser up-loader instead of flash upload utility ).

7-Warning messages should be friendly too!! (Oh dear! you didn't fill the product name filed. )->preferably with a scroll to that field.

- A/B Testing!! a lot of it!!

below some examples :

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

hope that was useful :) .

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is talk to as many of these "non-tech-savy" people as possible. Figure out what would make sense for them as a "hosted website creator service" setup process, how they would like to use it? Try to drill down until you figure out what you could design that would make that experience so good that they **simply couldn't live without it.**

After that start wireframing your interface to meet those needs.

I'd start with that.